# Discord Bot - Give roles after Message, Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a simple discord bot, that gives a role to a user after he gives the bot a certain command

On the command !role the user should get a role called Beta

I first tried this:

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
Client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author
    if member.bot:
        return
    if message.attachments:
        return
    print(message.content)
    print(str(message.author))


    if "role" in message.content:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Giving role.", color=0x00ff40)
        await message.channel.send(message.channel, embed=embed)
        role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Beta")
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)


client.run("BOT TOKEN")
```

But I always get the following problem: 
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'roles'`

Thanks a lot for taking time to read this and if you can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Beta")
```

You have to use

```
message.guild.roles
```

instead of:

```
server.roles
```

to access the list of roles, newer discord versions use guild instead of server to avoid confusion with voice servers.

Comment: Gives me then the error message has no attribute server Sir

Comment: @rocket Try message.guild.roles
it depends on the discord version you are using. Tell me if this works

Comment: now getting this tho
```AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Comment: That is some other unrelated problem . It has to do with `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")` . I believe your first question is answered

Comment: You maybe have an idea on how to solve this too? :)

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe use Client instead of client in the line `await client.add_roles(message.author, role)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191778/discussion-between-miguel-and-rocket).